# How to handle all 5 threads in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a simple Kotlin class that have one "lazy" property. I emulate that this property take a username from network and return Observable.

After it I try to retrieve this property for e.q. 5 times and receive unexpected result.

Here is source code of the sample class (Kotlin):

```
class LazyInitialization {

    private val username by lazy {
        println("lazy init started")
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println("lazy init finished")
        Observable.just("username")
    }


    fun print(number: Int) {
        println("Print started [$number]")
        username.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
            println("Return preference: [$it]")
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sample how I call it (Java):

```
LazyInitialization lazyInitialization = new LazyInitialization();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    lazyInitialization.print(i);
}
```

Output is:

```
I/System.out: Print started [0]
I/System.out: lazy init started
I/System.out: lazy init finished
I/System.out: Print started [1]
I/System.out: Print started [2]
I/System.out: Print started [3]
I/System.out: Print started [4]
I/System.out: Return preference: [username]
I/System.out: Return preference: [username]
```

As you see preference returned two times, but should return value 5 times.

And the other weird moment that if I improve output (added printing of the number)

```
println("Return preference: [$number] [$it]")
```

so print() method looks like this:

```
fun print(number: Int) {
        println("Print started [$number]")
        username.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
            println("Return preference: [$number] [$it]")
    }
}
```

then I got expected result:

```
I/System.out: Print started [0]
I/System.out: lazy init started
I/System.out: lazy init finished
I/System.out: Print started [1]
I/System.out: Print started [2]
I/System.out: Print started [3]
I/System.out: Print started [4]
I/System.out: Return preference: [0] [username]
I/System.out: Return preference: [1] [username]
I/System.out: Return preference: [2] [username]
I/System.out: Return preference: [3] [username]
I/System.out: Return preference: [4] [username]
```

Also I do not understand the reason why it's happens.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this behavior?

Comment: Actually I don't think you can predict this. The purpose of the lazy delegate is to thread safely initialize only once. This means you create the observable once. After it completes, no more values are emitted. Because you put a sleep there, I guess there's going to be some cases when all subscribers subscribe and get the value and some cases when only some get the value. How many times did you run this and on how many different devices?

Comment: Fred, it's regular behavior with same logs.

Once I use "number" value - all 5 times I get expected result.
Once I do not use "number" value in subscribe lambda - got unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm at a loss here. I thought this was related to some race condition, but I get the exact same results as you. The only thing I got so far is that it seems to be scheduler related. Swtiching to a scheduler that is not single threaded, I got 5 prints. Starting the looping outside the main thread also got me 5 prints. It doesn't seem to be related with the lazy part. I removed it and got the same results. Byte code seems ok to me. I don't get why introducing the `$number` would change this.